# Order of elements in perfectly balanced tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, insertion-order

I have a hard time visualizing how will my program insert the elements.
Here's the code that the teacher gave us:

```
int arr[] = { 3, -2, 11, 7, 12, 1, 4, 5, 33, 13 };
int n = 10;
int cnt = 0;

typedef struct node*po;

struct node {
    int data;
    po left;
    po right;
};

po ibd(int n) {
    po holder;
    if (n>0) {
        int nl = n / 2;
        int nr = n - nl - 1;
        holder = new node;
        holder->data = arr[cnt++];
        holder->left = ibd(nl);
        holder->right = ibd(nr);
        return holder;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I sadly can't understand and visualize how it puts the elements in the tree. From what I can understand it uses recursively divide and conquer algorithm to split the array into two parts and add the elements, however I can't understand which element becomes the root. Can somebody help me visualize how the tree would look after everything has been inserted?

Comment: You should step through the code with your debugger and see what it does.

Comment: You should consider using the c tag for this question, rather than the c++ tag.

Comment: when the teacher's function signature is `po ibd(int n)` you fear for the future of code clarity

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Not really, there's a `new` in there. But it's true that this is just C in disguise (and **bad** C at that).

Comment: By the way, in C++, you don't need `typedef struct`, the `typedef` is not necessary.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Actually, in that declaration, the `typedef` is necessary: the "primary" object of that declaration is the pointer type `po`. `struct node` is just "also" declared there. It's horrible code style, of course, but valid.

Comment: Sadly, the code you posted, only the ibd function, does not link the new node to the tree.  The `holder` variable is local, so the tree disappears when execution leaves the function.  You'll need to have a global root node.

Answer (score 0):

When working with trees, I like to draw a node something like this:

```
+--------------+---------------+  
|            Data              |  
+--------------+---------------+  
|  Pointer to  |   Pointer to  |  
| left subtree | right subtree |  
+--------------+---------------+
```

When I make one node point to another, I use arrows from the appropriate `left` or `right` pointer to the new node.  This helps me visualize the tree.

There are many resources that show how to draw trees.

Once the tree is drawn, follow the arrows when adding a new node.

Comment: Yes I can understand that and how to draw trees, however I'm having trouble with this exact example. Lets say I have the array: { 3, -2, 11, 7, 12, 1, 4, 5, 33, 13 }. What the function does is splitting the array into 2: n / 2 and n - n/2 - 1. So now I have 2 arrays: {3, -2, 11, 7, 12, 1} and {4, 5, 33, 13}. However, I can't understand which element becomes my root. Is it 1 (5h array element, since n/2 = 5), and then put the others left and right, or am I getting something wrong? I'd really understand how it works if somebody just drew me this current example.

Comment: According to this statement: `holder->data = arr[cnt++];`, your root data is 3, because `cnt` is zero and `arr[0] == 3`.

Comment: I suggest trashing the function and writing your own Binary Tree builder, one that **you** understand.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that first, sadly I have to learn this one for the exam, since it's required. Thank you :)